# Jquery datetimepicker problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

```
$('#id').datetimepicker({
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss' 
});
```

`datetimepicker()` jQuery is not working properly in Firefox.

Whenever I try to change the value of date then it adds 100 years to date.

This code is working fine in IE.

Please suggest solution to this problem.

Comment: Will an error message occur in the error console, if you execute your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please give details regarding JS file for datetimepicker. Which JS are you using?

I am using

http://www.projectcodegen.com/jquery.ui.datetimepicker.min.js

and its working fine with

```
$(function() {
        $('#id').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:MM:ss TT'
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must give us what js file you are using.
When you call this function?
body > onload event?
Check if the Dom is ready.
Give us what exception appears when dom is ready.